# Not able to subscribe to Platform events using cometD in visualforce or force.com site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, platform-event, guest-user, cometd

I am trying to subscribe to a Platform event in force.com site page in visualforce page. I am using cometD to subscribe.Using below code. It works internally in org. But when using the page on site page session id is null, so, it is not working. Is there any way to subscribe to platform event and access it on site page?

```
cometd.websocketEnabled = false;
                      var auth = 'OAuth ' + '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
                      var cometdURL = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+ (null != window.location.port ? (':'+window.location.port) : '') +'/cometd/48.0/';
                      
                      cometd.configure({
                          url: cometdURL,
                          requestHeaders: { Authorization: auth}
                      });
```

Comment: Is this a guest user Site?

Comment: Yes @cropredy, it is a guest user Site. Is there any way to subscribe to platform event for VF page used in site guest users?

Comment: If you had 100 guest user "sessions", then each would receive every CometD event -  and if the same logical user started a new guest user session, they'd get the CometD event again?

Comment: I think yes, both the session will get the events.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing the Streaming API from a public-facing Force.com Site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/accessing-the-streaming-api-from-a-public-facing-force-com-site)